# Override all shipping costs for a specific shipping class in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a number of shipping classes with prices set in multiple shipping zones. Is it possible to detect if ANY product within the cart belongs to a specific shipping class, and if so set the shipping cost to 0 and display a message?

I would like to use this mechanism for products which require special handling and would be shipped via freight. So if a customer's order contains any of these products the shipping quote would be provided manually post-sale.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shipping groups doesn't exist in Woocommerce… You are may be talking about shipping classes regarding Products.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You're right, wrong terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will set all shipping cost to zero, when a specific defined shipping method is found in cart items and will display a custom notice.

The second hooked function is optional and will display the custom notice in checkout page.

> You will have to temporarily "**Enable debug mode**" in Shipping settings under Shipping options *(tab)* to disable / clear caching.

In the code below define in each function your shipping class slug and your custom notice:

```
// Null shipping costs for a specific shipping class and display a message
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_class_null_shipping_costs', 10, 2);
function shipping_class_null_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    // HERE set your shipping class slug
    $shipping_class_slug = 'extra';

    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items and checking for the specific defined shipping class
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class_slug )
            $found = true;
    }

    // Set shipping costs to zero if shipping class is found
    if( $found ){
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            $has_taxes = false;
            // Targetting "flat rate" and local pickup
            if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id || 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id  ){
                // Set the cost to zero
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;

                // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                        $has_taxes = true;
                        // Set taxes cost to zero
                        $taxes[$key] = 0;
                    }
                }
                if( $has_taxes )
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
        // Clear duplicated notices
        wc_clear_notices();
        // Add a custom notice to be displayed
        wc_add_notice( __('My custom shipping message here.', 'woocommerce'), 'notice' );
    }
    return $rates;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'display_custom_shipping_message_in_checkout' );
function display_custom_shipping_message_in_checkout(){
    // HERE set your shipping class slug
    $shipping_class_slug = 'extra';

    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items and checking for the specific defined shipping class
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class_slug )
            $found = true;
    }

    if( $found ){
        // Display a custom notice
        wc_print_notice( __('My custom shipping message here.', 'woocommerce'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> Don't forget to **disable "debug mode"** in shipping settings once this has been tested once.

Comment: I'm just finishing the implementation of this now, it works to zero the cost out but still shows the user the form to select which shipping method they would like in the cart. Can this be disabled and in place of the form show a message telling them why they can't choose a shipping method? Thanks.

Comment: @LouisW Yes I suppose (everything is mostly possible)… You should may be better ask a new question with the necessary details and settings, the related customized code and everything useful.

Comment: Downvote. Doesn't work because it applies the free shipping to the total shipping costs not the shipping cost of a specific product which has a specific shipping class. Other products added to cart also get free shipping when only products from 1 shipping class should get free shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Shipping Class and Shipping Method for Free Shipping, assign that Class to the product you want to offer free shipping for, and then ensure that Free Shipping Method is set at the default shipping method.

Good Luck!

Comment: This wouldn't totally do it. I have 6 zones and 12 classes. Set up to add up all class totals to get the shipping total - how would I override all this if a product of a certain shipping class is present and display a message?